# How can I fix logic of my code ? I get runtime error and stackoverflow exception

Tags: logic

There are 4 friends A,B,C,D each having some amount of money which they share among themselves everyday until it could not be shared equally, For example A has 15$ , it shares 5,5,5 to B,C,D similarly B = 9$  shares 3$,3$,3$ to other three, and C with 21$ and D with 12$ does the same, so now A has 14, B has 16 and C has 12 and D has 15.
Next Day they will again share their updated money in a same manner. I have to count the days until they can share it equally,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPLks.jpg) and if amount can be share forever return -1. for ex: When All 4 has 3$.
However i was not able to pass all the test cases due to runtime error and stackoverflow exception.
My code:

class Program {

```
public int Friends(int a,int b, int c, int d, int count)
{ 
    int m = b/3 + c/3 + d/3;
    int n = c/3 + d/3 + a/3;
    int o = d/3 + a/3 + b/3;
    int p = a/3 + b/3 + c/3;
    a=m;
    b=n;
    c=o;
    d=p;
    count +=1;
    count = Friends(a,b,c,d,count);
    return count;
}
static void Main(){
    int count =0;
    Program p = new Program();
    int a = p.Friends(3,3,3,3, count);
    System.Console.WriteLine(a);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the function main() from the same class, or the function Friend() will be called recursively, creating new Program class instance, and so call main() again and again.